# use df command to show only the %used

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, grep

I found some other solutions like:
`df -Ph /oracle/archive | awk 'NR == 2{print $5}' | tr -d '%'`

but they seem a bit too much, and I thought something more elegant exists, as I'll be passing directly to `subprocess.check_output()` in `python2.7`.

Here is an example output of `df`:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        7508524 4890644   2258240  69% /
```

I want to only get the `69` value.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you very much

Comment: What's not elegant about that?  You pipe the output to **awk**, which says "extract line 2, field 5".  That pipes to the **translate** command, which turns the percent sign into a blank.  Short and direct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Shorter using python

`statvfs` will provide information on free or available blocks on a partition without need to call subprocess:

```
>>> import os
>>> st = os.statvfs('/')
>>> (st.f_blocks - st.f_bavail) / st.f_blocks
0.692345901307951
```

#### Shorter using df and awk

```
$ df -Ph /oracle/archive | awk 'NR == 2{print $5+0}'
69
```

Awk will treat `$5` as a string.  By adding zero to it, we force awk to convert it to a number and that eliminates the `%`.

#### Shorter using df and GNU grep

```
df -Ph /oracle/archive | grep -Po '\d+(?=%)'
69
```

`-o` tells grep to print only the matching string.  `\d+(?=%)` looks for digits followed by `%` but does not include `%` in the match.

This requires the `-P` option to grep which requires GNU grep.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
echo $(df --output=pcent /oracle/archive) | tr -d 'Use% '
```

The --output=pcent option selects only the percent used field.  However it also prints the header.

The echo command flattens the output into a single string.

The tr command deletes the unwanted characters being the header, leading spaces and percent signs.

Comment: I've been looking all over for this. How did you see `Use%` and somehow 'translate' that to `pcent`?

Comment: @Botspot the pcent is an option for the "output" argument of the df command.  This is specified in the man page for the df command.

Comment: `df --output=pcent /PATH | tr -d 'Use%\n '` seems more concise (this also strips the newline).

Answer (score 2):

```
df --output=pcent /oracle/archive |egrep -o "[0-9]+"
```

or set a variable:

```
pcent_used=$(df --output=pcent /oracle/archive |egrep -o "[0-9]+")
```

Answer (score -1):

What's not elegant about that? You pipe the output to **awk**, which says "extract line 2, field 5". That pipes to the **translate** command, which turns the percent sign into a blank. Short and direct.

To do this in Python is more code:

- Grab the second line of the returned string
- **split** that into a list of strings
- Take the 5th element of that list
- cut off the trailing '%' character
- print the result.

In full-on unreadable mode, it might look something like

```
print <system_call>[1].split()[4][:-1]
```

... where you already know the system call.

Which is easier to read and maintain?  Your choice.